# Creating a server, techniques to keep a service running (or blocked?)

Tags: java, serversocket

When creating a standalone server in Java (not using a container like tomcat/jetty), what are the various techniques to keep the service running and not ending?

I have seen where people use a ServerSocket (since you will be communicating with the service presumably), and they use ServerSocket.accept() which blocks until it receives a message. And this is usually done in a while loop:

```
while(...) {
   serverSocket.accept();
}
```

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept())

Is this the only way? If not, what other ways are there and any pros/cons with it?

Are there any libraries that help with building your own service, or its pretty much roll your own.

Comment: Is using sockets a primary requirement? There are techniques using a JMS server to send/receive messages.

Comment: there is no requirment, I just want to know what options there are when creating your own custom server.

Comment: Alright then, one option not mentioned is using a JMS server like Apache ActiveMQ. You do not need to manage any sockets. You create queues and listeners and your server waits for messages to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various libraries that help you roll your own Windows/Unix service in Java:

- [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/)
- [Akuma](http://akuma.kohsuke.org/)
- [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)

How you keep the application running depends on the actual needs of your application. If your application is a server, you would normally want to listen for incoming connections which usually involves some sort of blocking/polling. How you do that again depends on the type of server you want to build. Of the generic solutions there's the ServerSocket class and its method accept() that you already mentioned. Another possibility is to use java.nio and implement a reactor which provides a single-threaded server that can handle multiple connections at once (see http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpjslides/nio.pdf for details), but may be a bit hard to grasp and debug.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a multi-threaded server.
Each time the server accepts a connection, the server creates a thread to handle sending/reciving to that client. If you do not use threads in your server, it will only be able to handle one connection at a time. 
So, as you meantioned, the server loops infinitly and listens for incomming connections:

```
while(true){
    serverSocket.accept();
    ClientHandler c = new ClientHandler(serverSocket);
```

A instance of the class ClientHandler will be created each time a connection is accepted. This class implements Runnable, and loops for incomming messages using getInputStream and getOutputStream on that socket:

```
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable{
DataInputStream in;
DataOutputStream out;

//ClientHandler constructor
   public ClientHandler(Socket s) throws IOException{
        in= new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        thread.start();
}
```

The run method:

```
public void run() { 
   while(true){
       String temp="";
       while ((temp = (String) in.readUTF()) != null){ // Read from the input stream each iteration. When temp is not null a message is recived             
            System.out.println(temp);
```

Please that the above code does not take into account different exceptions that might occur and is very basic. But it should give you a basic idea on how a server using Sockets can be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick solution (in a testing environment only!) you can go for something often dubbed as "Enterprise Loop" (because it is too often found in production systems):

```
while (true) 
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // maybe log
    }
```

However, this is not good style in the production code.
(see [1] for a parody of that idiom)

To create a service, you want one of the libraries from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10819366/3888050).

If you "just need multithreading", have a look into the Java concurrency framework. I stronly suggest reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/), as multi-threading is much more that just starting another thread and errors are hard to debug.

[1] http://blog.antiblau.de/2016/01/26/java-enterprise-loop/